# Calculate vector from two points and angle

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, angle

I have three points:

```
     P1 (5065, 423)
     P2 (4935, 281)
     P3 (0, 0)
```

[image]

I calculated the angle between `P3,P2` and `P2,P1`, as result I got: `3.878736`

**Now I would like to test my result, by construction the vector `P3,P2` with my calculated angel and the points `P1`and `P2`**

Next i would check if the point `P3 (0,0)` is located on the constructed vector:

**How can I get a vector from this 3 factors? Thanks**

[image]

---

---

*The angle I calculated with this formula and code:*

```
MY.math = {
    angle: function(p1, p2, p3){
        if (p3){
            return Math.abs(MY.math.angle(p1, p3) - MY.math.angle(p2, p3));
        }

        var angle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);

        while (angle < 0){
            angle += 2 * Math.PI;
        }

        return angle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use rotation of the vector  $P_1P_2$ around the z- axis. Take  $P_1=(5065,423,0)$,  $P_2=( 4925,281,0)$, and consider the rotation matrix around the z-axis  $$ Rot_z(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}   \cos(\theta) &  -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\  \sin(\theta)  &  \cos(\theta) &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Where  $\theta=  3.878736$. Then your vector $P_2P_3$ is  $$ P_2P_3=Rot_z(\theta) P_2P_1 $$ You will get a $3$D vector  whose last component is zero, taking the first two components you will get your  $ P_2P_3$.

Hope this helps you.